# What is the opposite of .contains for VTL?

Tags: variables, contains, velocity, vtl, velocity-template-language

I have the potential for two different outputs based on three additional attributes and the values they contain:

```
#if($f3=="Banana" && $f2.contains("Mud"))
This is gross
#end
```

Works just fine.
However if I want to add in an `#elseif` to check for `$f2 NOT containing "Mud"`, that's where I'm stuck.

Comment: Sorted it out:
#if($f3=="Banana" && $f2.contains("Mud"))
This is gross
#elseif($f3=="Banana" && !$f2.contains("Mud"))
Bananas Foster For Everyone!
#end

Answer (score 1):

Add inner if with else:

```
#if($f3=="Banana")
  #if ($f2.contains("Mud")) contains
  #else not contains
  #end
#end
```